# Splitting line layer at polygon's boundary of polygon layer using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a line layer and a polygon layer in PostgreSQL 9.2, PostGIS 2.0. How can I split every line each time it crosses a polygon's boundary?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I can't test it on larger data set so it might not be fastest but should work.

If the polygons don't intersect (seems to be what you want) this will work. With `ST_INTERSECTION(<line>,<polygon>)` we can get lines inside of polygons (one line per row), with `ST_Difference(<line>,ST_UNION(<polygon>))` we can get a geometry colection that holds pieces of line that don't fit inside any of the polygons. So now we just have to put those two results in one format and `UNION` them:

```
    WITH
    lines_in_polygons AS(
      SELECT ST_INTERSECTION(line,polygon) as inter
      FROM
        line AS l,
        poly AS c
    ),
    diff AS (
      SELECT ST_Difference(l.line,ST_UNION(polygon)) geom FROM 
      line AS l
      JOIN poly AS p ON
      ST_INTERSECTS(l.line,p.polygon)
      GROUP BY l.line)

    SELECT ST_GeometryN(geom,n) 
    FROM diff AS d
    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT 
     generate_series(1,ST_NumGeometries(geom)) as n FROM diff) n
    UNION
    SELECT inter
    FROM lines_in_polygons;
```

If the polygons do intersect...I'll try tommorow.

Comment: Are "line" and "polygon" geometry columns in their layer? I've found that ST_UNION() is very slow on my polygon layer. Can you modify the query so that "line" will difference with st_union of "lines_in_polygons"? I think the result will be much faster. As I am new to PostGIS and databases in general, please bear with me. Thank you very much!

Comment: It works (with line layer named 'line' and geometry column named 'line', polygon layer named 'poly' and geometry column named 'polygon'). Thanks!