# Splitting lines at polygon intersection with attributes saving using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

This relates to [Splitting line layer at polygon's boundary of polygon layer using PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56874) but what about keeping the attributes.

[image]

Having

- line_layer (id, geom, attribute1, attribute2)
- poly_layer (id, geom, attribute3, attribute4)

How do I split the lines after polygons and preserve the attributes for each segment?

My current code is:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id, *
   FROM ( WITH lines_in_polygons AS (
                 SELECT st_intersection(ln.geom, a.geom) AS inter
               FROM line_layer ln,
                polygon_layer a
            ), diff AS (
             SELECT st_difference(ln.geom, st_union(pl.geom)) AS geom
               FROM line_layer ln
          JOIN polygon_layer pl ON st_intersects(ln.geom, pl.geom)
         GROUP BY ln.geom
            )
             SELECT st_geometryn(d.geom, n.n) AS geom
               FROM diff d
         CROSS JOIN ( SELECT generate_series(1, st_numgeometries(diff.geom)) AS n
                       FROM diff) n
    UNION
             SELECT lines_in_polygons.inter
               FROM lines_in_polygons) coco
  WHERE geometrytype(coco.geom) = 'LINESTRING';
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding your params to this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56998/16594 ? It should just work if you  add the correct columns.

Comment: I have tried but it seems my sql skills are not that good (or maybe there are some tricks that I am not yet aware of)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass the attributes through both CTEs. Using * for all attributes:

```
WITH
lines_in_polygons AS(
  SELECT l.*,ST_INTERSECTION(l.geom,c.geometry) as inter
  FROM
    lines AS l,
    temppolys AS c
),
diff AS (
  SELECT l.*,ST_Difference(l.geom,ST_UNION(p.geometry)) geom FROM 
  lines AS l
  JOIN temppolys AS p ON
  ST_INTERSECTS(l.geom,p.geometry)
  GROUP BY l.fid)

SELECT *,ST_GeometryN(geom,n) 
FROM diff AS d
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT 
 generate_series(1,ST_NumGeometries(geom)) as n FROM diff) n
UNION
SELECT inter
FROM lines_in_polygons;
```

Comment: I am new and tried this code but get this: ERROR:  column reference "geom" is ambiguous LINE 19:  generate_series(1,ST_NumGeometries(geom)) as n FROM diff) n