# how to split/cut a linestring with another a linestring

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to cut a linestring with another linestring where both of lines are coincidence using SQL to get a multilinestring?

Comment: SQL or QGIS? If SQL database wichich one? Please be more specific cause correct answer to your question could be 'YES', but I think it won't help you...

Comment: I use sql both in PostGIS and QGIS. I need the command in sql to get that query. The real problem is : I have a river (as linestring) which part of it crosses a country, so i can get that part. The query is how to get another part of the river which does not crosses that country. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

OK, so:

1. To get part of river laying inside of polygon you have to use [ST_Intersection](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersection.html) function
2. To get part of river laying outside of polygon you have to use [ST_Difference](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html) function

Resolution of similar problem is wroten [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56874/how-to-split-line-layer-at-polygons-boundary-of-a-polygon-layer), so I think there is no reason to rewrite this query...

Let me know if it wont work :)